# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Joomla's [Moderator election #5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

[image: Irata]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!